# How to speed up semantic-ui builds?

Tags: semantic-ui

I've got *everything* turned on; every module, element, view, collection (as I was just checking them all out).

Now I'm trying to actually build something but the build takes about 10 seconds every time.

I thought I could just comment out all the modules I'm not using so that (a) it wouldn't build them and (b) they wouldn't bloat my project.

I tried commenting stuff out of the `theme.config` but no improvement.
I tried commenting stuff out of the `semantic.less` but no improvement.

Is there a way to speed the build by excluding unused pieces? If so, how?

Comment: So far the only way I've worked out is to start over completely from scratch and elect for a `custom` install omitting the modules I'm not thinking of using.  Surely there is a better way?!

Answer (score 1):

If you used the npm or meteor, a `semantic.json` file is automatically generated for you in the root of your project. In that file you can include list of the components you want to include.

```
"components": [
    "reset",
    "site",
    "button"
  ]
```

You can read more [here](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html#semanticjson)